# How do I utilize two catergorical columns, to create one percentage column in R?

Tags: r, percentage, categorical-data

I have a df with two categorical variables: team and home_win.
I would like to obtain percentage of home wins per team (1 = home_win; 2 = home_loss).
However, I can't figure out how to use two catergorical variables two create a percentage.

Please help!

| team | home_win | total_games |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "red" | 1 | 3 |
| "blue | 1 | 1 |
| "orange" | 2 | 1 |
| "red" | 1 | 3 |
| "red" | 2 | 3 |

```
  data.frame(
    team = c("red", "blue", "orange", "red", "red"),
    home_win = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2),
    total_games = c(3, 1, 1, 3, 3)
  )
```

| team | home_win | total_games | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "red" | 1 | 3 | 66.66 |
| "blue | 1 | 1 | 100 |
| "orange" | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| "red" | 1 | 3 | 66.66 |
| "red" | 2 | 3 | 66.66 |

Comment: To find the percentage, you should have some column mentioning the total `home games` of a particular team. Can you show us that?

Comment: @its_deb I currently do not have such a column but I can add it in. I will update the code

Comment: Yeah, you don't need the `total_games` column. I misunderstood the question, sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this. If we exchange the `2` for `0`, we can simply take the mean for each team.

```
library(dplyr)
dat$home_win = as.numeric(gsub(2, 0, dat$home_win))
> dat %>% group_by(team) %>% summarise(win_perc = mean(home_win) * 100)
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  team   win_perc
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 blue      100  
2 orange      0  
3 red        66.7
```

Or if you want to keep the other cols:

```
dat$home_win = as.numeric(gsub(2, 0, dat$home_win))
dat %>% group_by(team) %>% mutate(win_perc = mean(home_win) * 100)
```

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
# Groups:   team [3]
  team   home_win total_games win_perc
  <chr>     <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1 red           1           3     66.7
2 blue          1           1    100  
3 orange        0           1      0  
4 red           1           3     66.7
5 red           0           3     66.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `base` method:

Convert the 2's in the data frame with 0 (as 0 implies a loss): `df[df$home_win==2,]$home_win<-0`

Then use `tapply`:

```
Avg<-tapply(df$home_win,df$team,mean)
percentage<-Avg[df$team]*100
cbind(df,percentage)

#    team home_win percentage
#1    red        1   66.66667
#2   blue        1  100.00000
#3 orange        0    0.00000
#4    red        1   66.66667
#5    red        0   66.66667
```

Note: You don't need the `total games` column, you can remove it...